# How does temperature work when a statistical ensemble has discrete energy levels?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

Say I’m working with a system which is a collection of N non-interacting spins. For simplicity, I’ll pretend that the energy of each upwards spin is 1, and that downwards spins have no energy. The energy of a microstate is then simply the number of upwards spins it has. Now, since I’m working in the microcanonical ensemble, I’ll declare that my only knowledge of the system is that it has a fixed energy E, meaning the exact microstate of the system is equally likely to be any of the ones which have energy E. I then have the entropy S of my ensemble, which is defined by E, so I have the entropy S(E) of the macrostate with energy E.

As far as I understand, the (inverse) temperature T(E) of this macrostate with energy E is the partial derivative of entropy with respect to the energy, as evaluated at energy E. (Basically, the sensitivity of the entropy of the macrostate to tiny changes in the energy about the value E).

But how does this derivative make sense when I only have a finite, discrete set of values that the energy of my system could take, each of them separated by units of 1. And thus the resulting change in entropy doesn’t make any sense when I make a tiny change in the energy, because I can’t just make a tiny change in energy. I have to go in steps of 1, or else my system isn’t defined.

So... Does this mean that temperature is only defined when the energy of a system can take values in the continuum?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing seems to me like a system of non-intarcting two-level particles. The temperature for such system is derived [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature#Noninteracting_two-level_particles).

As you can see, the temperature for such systems can be pretty wild. It can be even negative!

Comment: As you can see, they take the central difference instead of the derivative.

Comment: Ahhh... I see. So the finite difference ε they’re using is the spacing of levels around the chosen value of E... That makes sense, and it certainly reduces to the usual definition for continuous-energy systems in the thermodynamic limit. What I don’t understand is why all the thermodynamics references I’ve seen always leave these subtleties out. It seems pretty important to me...